# form in wordpress that writes to many tables (with different columns)

Tags: wordpress

Currently, I'm using tablepress to output different info using a table format. I want users to be able to add to existing information. I need a form in wordpress that saves user posts to these different tables. How should I go about this? Sorry if I sound stupid but I'm soft on html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert in posts table using custom form, you can use wp_insert_post().

This function inserts posts (and pages) in the database. It sanitizes variables, does some checks, fills in missing variables like date/time, etc. It takes an object as its argument and returns the post ID of the created post (or 0 if there is an error).

Reference : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post